# How to make a dictionary from a book txt file without using Json?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have a txt file which contains a poem in this format.

She says my hair smells
like corn tortillas.
I raise an eyebrow.
After all those days
and papaya shampoos,

My goal is to make a dictionary and asign a key to each line of the poem.

For example:

content = {1 : "She says my hair smells", 2 : "like corn tortillas."}` and e.t.c

I am have this code written:

```
with open("dictionaries/questions.txt", "r") as f:
d_black = {}
key = 0
for line in f:
    x = line.split("\n")
    d_black[key] = x
print(d_black)
```

But for some reason it creates an extra empty string " " and a list. Here is the output I get:

```
{0: ["She says my hair smells", '']}
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `split()` function it returns a list of elements, that's why you are seeing a list.

You can use `Dictionary Comprehension` to accomplish this:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    result = {k:v.split('\n')[0] for k,v in enumerate(f)}
    print(result)
    [Output]: {0: 'She says my hair smells', 1: 'like corn tortillas.', 2: 'I raise an eyebrow.', 3: 'After all those honeysuckle', 4: 'and papaya shampoos'}
```

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrShane The function `enumerate()` for each iteration returns a counter (k) and the current value of f (v). Basically, `for k(counter), v(value) in enumerate(f)` in the first iteration will return 0 for the counter and 'she says...' for the value. This results in K being the key of the dictionary and v.split('\n') the value. For more details [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). And please, mark my answer as accepted.